# Why does this usage of C++17 if constexpr fail?

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to use C++17 `if constexpr` for conditional compilation, but it does not behave the way I expect.

For example, with the code below, C++ still compiles the code defined by the macro `X2`,

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define X1 pp("x")
#define X2 pp("x", "x")

void pp(const std::string str)
{
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, int> map;

   if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(map)>)
      X2;
   else
      X1;
}
```

and spits out this error messages:

```
1.c:6:23: error: too many arguments to function ‘void pp(std::__cxx11::string)’
 #define X2 pp("x", "x")
                       ^
1.c:18:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘X2’
   X2;
   ^~
```

How can I skip compilation of X2?

Comment: `if constexpr` is a replacement for `std::enable_if`, not for `#if`.

Comment: I recently did a [quiz on this issue](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1279298831599857664) and I [note in my answer](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1281271387261263872) that it was not meant to act like e.g. disarm `static_asserts` etc

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is not possible outside the template!

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

> **Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked.** `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     if constexpr(false) {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

---

> Any idea how to skip compilation of **X2**?

One option is to provide a template function for that.

```
template<typename T>
void test()
{
   if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<T>)
      X2;
   else
      X1;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, int> map;
   test<decltype(map)>();   // now chooses the X1
}
```

Thanks to *[@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat)* and *[@MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters)*. As they pointed out, **the above solution is ill-formed NDR** (therefore, compiling with [MSVC compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/z11bYn) does not make any sense and on the other hand
the [GCC and clang at least catch this](https://godbolt.org/z/aseosr) by providing some compiler errors )
which has been detailed in the [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046397/why-does-this-usage-of-c17-if-constexpr-fail/63059201#63059201)'s,
answer!

Therefore can we skip the compilation of **X2**?

Unfortunately, **NO** as per your code!!
The [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) will be executed before the compilation of the translation unit.
Therefore one can not provide the type information (i.e. `decltype(map)`) to `#if` directives.
Hence for your case, there is no other way.

**Good lessons from this post**:

- Your program is, however, is a good example to avoid such kind macro
  and `constexpr if` mixing.
- Secondly, check the correctness of the code by different
  compilers if possible!

I would suggest having a function overload for `PP` (and of course there are many other ways) to your case, by which you could get a well-formed code:

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6PW6Gs).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>

void pp(const std::string& str)
{
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

template<typename... T> void pp(const T&... args)
{
   // do something with args!
}

template<typename T>
constexpr void test()
{
   if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<T>)
      pp("x", "x"); // call with args
   else
      pp("x"); // call with string
}
```

Comment: Your use of `if constexpr` is ill-formed NDR because of [`[temp.res]/8.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1). Both GCC and Clang seem to reject it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Why NDR? The template _is_ instantiated. And it seems like there are 4 `T`'s for which test can be instantiated (`std::nullptr_t`, plus cv-qualified.)

Comment: @MSalters The template is instantiated, but the first branch (the invalid one) isn't. If the first branch was instantiated (`test<std::nullptr_t>()`), then yes, it would be just ill-formed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: 8.1 says "The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
(8.1) no valid specialization can be generated for ((a template) or (a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template) **and** (the template is not instantiated))". I've made the individual conditions clear, and it's obvious that the last condition is not met.

Comment: @MSalters Huh, I didn't notice that. I see your point. Are you saying instatiating the `test` makes the code well-formed? If so, I argue it's a defect in the wording, and it should say "the template or the substatement of constexpr if are not instantiated". It doesn't make sense to stop checking all the branches just because the enclosing template was instantiated.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: No, I'd expect it to be ill-formed, diagnostic required. The purpose of 8.1 seems to be to give implementations the liberty to delay certain checks until instantiation time. But instantiations that do spot the error earlier are allowed to report it even without instantiation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218452/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-msalters).

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejcf9E).

Comment: Are you sure this solution is correct? To be honest, it *looks* correct to me, but I'm skeptical when clang and gcc trunk don't compile c++17 code.

Comment: @cigien It's ill-formed NDR, see the first comment. (Or just ill-formed, if MSalters is correct.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, thanks, that discussion is interesting. Interesting to see so many upvotes on an incorrect answer. I upvoted too without checking, because it looks correct :p

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, just now I finished reading. I realize my mistake now. Thanks a lot for pointing out a big mistake, which seems to me also correct because of my MSVS! Let me update my answer!

Comment: @JeJo From what I've seen, MSVC tends to be the least compliant of the three major compilers. :/

Comment: Some unimportant things regarding the edit: 1. In the last snippet, the `pp(T&&... args)` overload is going to be selected in both cases: using a forwarding reference means it will be preferred even for a single `std::string` parameter unless it's a `const` lvalue. Suggest using the same flavor of references in both overloads, so the second one should be `pp(const T &... args)`. And even then, the arguments are not `std::string`s, so the template overload will be preferred. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] 2. From my point of view at least, MSalters didn't dig up any wording that proves the `if constexpr` snippet being ill-formed (not NDR), so it has to fall under `[temp.res]/8.1` and be ill-formed NDR, so MSVC is not wrong to not diagnose this.

Comment: @JeJo Thanks for the answer and suggestions. The function `pp` here is just an example to illustratie my question. The original function is generated by Thrift compiler so seemingly not possible to be overloaded.

Comment: @MSalters the reason this error is NDR is because proving every possible instantiation of a template is invalid regardless of template parameters isn't possible to solve in the general case (the type system is pretty complex). If you think a diagnostic is always required then thats a defect in the standard because an implementation is impossible.

Answer (score 9):

`if constexpr` is not really a "conditional compilation".

Outside of a template, it works just like the regular `if` (except it wants the condition to be `constexpr`).

The other answers suggest putting it inside of a template (and making the condition depend on the template parameter), but that's not enough. (It seems to work in MSVC, but not in GCC & Clang.) That's because:

> [`[temp.res]/8.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1) (emphasis mine)
>
> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. ...
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template **or a substatement of a constexpr if statement** within a template and the template is not instantiated, ...

So if you can't make a valid instantiation for an `if constexpr` branch (that is, if for all possible template arguments the branch is invalid), then the program is ill-formed NDR (which effectively means "invalid, but the compiler might not be smart enough to give you an error").

<sup>(As noted by @MSalters, the standard says "and the template is not instantiated", rather than "and the template **or the substatement of the constexpr if** are not instantiated". I argue that it's a defective wording, because it makes no sense otherwise: there doesn't seem to be any other wording to check validity of discarded branches, so it would make the code well-formed **only when** the enclosing template **is** instantiated, and ill-formed NDR otherwise. See [discussion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63046598/2752075).)</sup>

There seem to be no workarounds for that, and no good solutions for your problem.

You *could* make the function call itself depend on the template parameter, but it's probably cheating, as it requires shadowing `pp` (or doing `#define pp …`).

```
template <typename F>
void test(F pp) // Note parameter shadowing the global `pp` for the macros.
{
    std::map<std::string, int> map;

    if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(map)>)
        X2;
    else
        X1;
}

int main()
{
    test([](auto &&... params)
    {
        pp(decltype(params)(params)...);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is that this is impossible. I think I agree :) I have to say, I really dislike the "solution" though. Shadowing the name of the macro is kind of skirting the issue.

Comment: @cigien Yep, it's probably cheating. Edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7):

Outside of a template, even the false branch of an `if constexpr` is fully checked. In general, for this, one would need to

- either use a `#if` pre-processor directive,
- or put the `if constexpr` code into a template.

In your case, you can not use `#if` because your condition depends on type information that is not available to the pre-processor.

Also, you can not use `constexpr if` because the expansion of the macro `X2` is always ill-formed, for any possible template parameter.

You probably need to rethink why you want to have a macro whose expansion is never valid.

Comment: ... and this goes to show that if constexpr is a half-measure. I wish we could have static if like D.

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, that would be nice. That's what I used to think `if constexpr` did :p

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you can modify the `pp` to behave the way I think it should behave:

```
void pp(auto const &...args){
    ((std::cout << std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...) << std::endl;
}
```

[Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xT6vPf)

If that's not possible, then I suggest fixing the X2 to a code that compiles at least.

If changing X2 is not possible, then I suggest shadowing the pp for when calling x2 even though It's the best solution of course:

```
if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(map)>) {
    auto pp = [] (auto const &...args){
        ((std::cout << std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...) << std::endl;
    };
    X2;
} else {
    X1;
}
```

[Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Mzx35T)