# C++ if constexpr using a constexpr bool equivalent to plain if?

Tags: c++, if-statement, constexpr, if-constexpr

Are the follow snippets functionally equivalent given the conditional variable that's being checked has been marked as `constexpr`?

Additionally, is this a correct usage of `if constexpr` or is it's intended application within a templatized context.

```
constexpr bool kOn = false;

// Snippet 1
if (kOn) { return true; }

// Snippet 2
if constexpr (kOn) { return true; }
```

Comment: if constexpr only has its useful properties (i.e. what everyone expects) only inside a template, 
and only when depending on its containing templats  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63046397/817643

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512248/817643

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the two `if`s are not equivalent.

The 1st one is evaluated at runtime, and code in both of its branches must be well-formed at compile-time.

The 2nd one is evaluated at compile-time, and code in its unused branch can be ill-formed since its dead code that gets removed by the compiler.

`if constexpr` is not dependent on templates.

Comment: It very much is dependent on templates to be of any use.

Comment: @Artyer, snippet 1 fails at compile-time, if the discarded branch is ill-formed. But snippet 2 compiles even if discarded branch is ill-formed. The diagnostic and compilation behavior changes according to the choice.

Comment: @Red.Wave - *"snippet 2 compiles even if..."* [No it doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IA5pgTeZgxpcksHh).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so it ended up like `static_assert` too. That's a pitty.

Comment: actually purpose of `if constexpr` was to force materialization of const expression, the ability to discard statements if not value-dependant is a by-product feature.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `if constexpr`, the branch not taken (the `else` if the condition was `true` or the first statement if the condition was `false`) becomes a discarded statement and gains exactly 3 "special powers".

- If it is in a template and the condition was value-dependent (e.g., `if constexpr (B)` where you had a template-head `template<bool B>`), the discarded branch isn't instantiated at all when the specialization is instantiated.
- Entities inside a discarded branch are still odr-used but do not require a definition:

  ```
  int x();
  int main() {
      if constexpr (false) x();  // Does not require a definition of x
      if (false) x();  // Requires a definition of x
  }
  ```
- Return statements in a discarded branch do not affect `auto` type deduction:

  ```cpp
  auto f() {
      if constexpr (false) return 0;
      return 0L;
  }  // OK: auto deduced as long

  auto g() {
      if (false) return 0;
      return 0L;
  }  // Error: two return statements with different types.
  ```

And, of course, the difference that `if (x)` doesn't force `x` to be a constant expression, whereas `if constexpr (x)` does.

So in a non-template context, there isn't much difference with your `constexpr bool kOn = false;`. The compiler will still check both branches to see if they compile with an `if constexpr`.

Comment: Just goes to show how poor choice of names can confuse people. A "discarded statement" isn't necessarily being discarded in the intuitive sense. That just messes with people.